# while parse the HTML using NSXMLParser, not full data in iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, ios, ipad

while parse the xml, not full data is getting after some word line end with read more

below three codes are in a single html page i spited that for better understanding.

i am parsing this in to my iPhone app using NSXMLParser.
problem is its parsing till `<Style>` below then it stops parsing from the text after that and completely ignores the data below the text!!!

```
<head>

        <title>North Mobile County Middle School: Latest News > "1st Annual NMCK-8 Christmas Music Program"</title>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="X-UA-COMPATIBLE" CONTENT="IE=EmulateIE9">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScripts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScripts/NiceTitles.js"></script>


    <style type="text/css">
```

i am splitting  the code for better understanding

```
!--

body {
    margin:0; padding:0;
    background: #fff;}  
body, td {
    font: normal 13px "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#333;}
/***********************************************/
/* Links
/***********************************************/ 

a:link, a:visited {
    color: #CD0000;
    text-decoration: none;}
a:hover, a:active { 
    color: #06f;
    text-decoration: underline;}

img {border: 0;}
```

i am splitting the code for better understanding

```
#MainPageArea {padding: 0 15px 15px 15px}
</style>
    <link href="http://images.pcmac.org/SiSFiles/Schools/AL/MobileCounty/NorthMobileMiddle/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <link href="Common/CommonIncludes/Template11/IEStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="Shortcut Icon" type="image/ico" href="http://images.pcmac.org/SiSFiles/Schools/AL/MobileCounty/NorthMobileMiddle/images/favicon.ico" />

</head>
<body class="DefaultPage">
    <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="986" border="0" id="PageWrapper">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <div id="Header">
```

i am using code as below:

```
-(id) loadHtmlByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{

    NSURL       *url        = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData      *nsData     = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    elementArray            = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    parser                  = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:nsData];
    parser.delegate         = self;
    [parser parse];

    currentHTMLElement = [HtmlElement alloc];

    return self;
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"%@",elementname);
    currentHTMLElement = [[HtmlElement alloc] autorelease];
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    NSLog(@"%@",elementname);
if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"head"])
    {
        currentHTMLElement.tag = elementname;
        currentHTMLElement.value = currentNodeContent;
        [elementArray addObject:currentHTMLElement];
        currentHTMLElement = nil;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
       // NSLog(@"x%@",elementArray);
    }
```

can i know were i was struck

Comment: Is your file well-formed XML?

Comment: its HTML, ya its reading data till the text in middle but not after that

Comment: Can you run it through an XML checker?

Comment: i have no idea about XML checker

Answer (score 1):

You should only use the `NSXMLParser` class to parse stuff that’s actually XML. HTML is not, except if it’s XHTML, which your source is not: The `meta` tags aren’t closed and your `style` tag starts with a comment that is never closed (which, I guess, is the reason why the parser never reads past that); also, the `title`’s text node contents should only contain escaped versions of  `>` and `"` (the escape sequences being `&gt;` and `&quot;`).

If you’re in control of the HTML, try changing it to be XML- (and, thus, XHTML-) compliant. If you can’t change the HTML, try tag soup parsing, for example with [hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tutorial for Parsing HTML page
http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios